# jQuery multiple else if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to set a padding on a div based on the window height size. I simply couldn't find a better working way to center my content div vertically in another div with unknown dimensions. My code is as it follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var home_content = $('#home-content');

            if(window_height <= 600) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "13px"});
            } else if(window_height > 600 && window_height <= 768) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "97px"});
            } else if(window_height > 768 && window_height <= 800) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "113px"});
            } else if(window_height > 800 && window_height <= 900) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "163px"});
            } else if(window_height > 900 && window_height <= 1050) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "238px"});
            } else if(window_height > 1050 && window_height <= 1080) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "253px"});
            } else if(window_height > 1080 && window_height <= 1200) {
                home_content.css({"padding-top", "313px"});
            } else {

            }
     });
    </script>
```

It is not working. My web site is stuck on the preloader and simply won't load anyhing. Any ideas where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Check the "console" when nothing works. You should get some output there.

Comment: You can clean up your code by getting rid of the tests on the left hand side of each `&&` operator. For example, your first `if()` has already tested if it is `<= 600`, and failed, so there's no need to test that it's `> 600` since you already know it is. ...Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aa5aK/

Comment: What are you trying to do, vertically center a div within a container?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing:

```
{"padding-top", "13px"}
```

to:

```
{"padding-top":"13px"}
```

and so on...

### Note

The thing is that you can assign css style with jquery in two ways:

```
$("#element").css('padding', '30px');
```

(if you want to edit/add *one* style setting), or:

```
$("#element").css({'padding':'30px'});
```

(with this method, you can add how many settings as you like, just separate them with `,`, kudos to @dollarvar for pointing this out).

The problem in your code was that you had an *,* instead of *:*.

Comment: do you have the correct selector ($("#home-content"))?

Comment: @MomchilKaramitev Give us the output of the console, you know what that is?

Comment: @DanielLisik Ok, you just have to add, that `.css()` supports only one style setting, and the `.css({})` "object" several...or around that line. Then you have the most complete `.css` 101 here. ;)

Comment: I tried the method with the : instead of , but it was giving me error in the console, so I changed it back to "," and now it works. I think I just had to remove the curly braces out of the .css attribute. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @MomchilKaramitev what error was displayed in the console?

Comment: Probably tried the `:` without the `{` and `}`. There's something to be said for knowing basic syntax and reading documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can remove `{}` and use

```
 home_content.css("padding-top", "13px");
```

instead of

```
home_content.css({"padding-top", "13px"});
```

Comment: I think that actually helped. My site now loads just fine and the padding is applied to the element. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative instead of the JavaScript hack, you could make use of [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to specify the CSS rules to apply ([example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)). It does depend on exactly which browsers you need to support, http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries.

```
@media (max-height : 599px) {
    #home-content { padding-top: 13px; }
}

@media (min-height : 768px) {
    #home-content { padding-top: 97px; }
}

@media (min-height : 800px) {
    #home-content { padding-top: 113px; }
}

@media (min-height : 900px) {
    #home-content { padding-top: 163px; }
}

...
```

This will also change the padding automatically when you resize your browser window, it's the same technique used for Responsive design.

**EDIT:**

BUT, re-reading your actual question, it looks like your are trying to vertically center a div within a container. You really don't need to use any Javascript, you can do this completely with CSS and it will be much smoother: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container { 
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative;
}

#home-container { 
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLJoA)